# Best way to data model the same Java Class with different functionalities

Tags: java, oop, data-modeling

### Case:

Normally product objects have these attributes:

1. name
2. price

But during promotion week, while the majority of products still only have name and price as attribute, **some** selected products get an additional attribute:

- color

But after the promotion week these prior promoted products will loose their color attribute and become a standard product again.

### Current Implementation:

I have 2 Classes -> Product and ProductPromotion

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private ProductPromotion promotion;

    public Product(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setProductPromotion(ProductPromotion promotion) {
        this.promotion = promotion;
    }
}


public class ProductPromotion {

    private Color color;

    public ProductPromotion (Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

As you can see, Product has a unilateral reference to ProductPromotion. Default product objects have a null reference to its ProductPromotion, while products with promotion, I simply do: `myproduct.setProductPromotion(new ProductPromotion(Color.RED));`

Whenever I decide that the promotion for a myproduct is over, I just do:
`myproduct.setProductPromotion(null);`

### My ISSUE:

I don't really like to have a null reference to ProductPromotion for each non-promoted Product, for this kind of modelling is not really beautiful. I mean why do we need to keep a placeholder if the placeholder just holds nothing (at least for non-promoted products). So I would like to ask the experienced coders out there for a better implementation of this functionality.

### Further thinking:

With your input and your thoughts I was able to come up with a new approach and I really welcome your thought on this:

I would split up the ProductPromotion class into a default and a promoted version:

```
public class ProductPromotion {
    private boolean promotionDisabled;

    public ProductPromotion() {
        setPromotionDisabled(true);
    }

    public boolean isPromotionDisabled () {
        return promotionDisabled;
    }

    public boolean setPromotionDisabled (boolean value) {
        promotionDisabled = value;
    }
}

public class ProductPromotionEnabled extends ProductPromotion {
    private Color color;

    public ProductPromotion (Color color) {
        super(false);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor () {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

So I would create a single defaultPromotionObject of type **ProductPromotion** having referenced to any non promoted objects. While objects in promotion would point to a promotionEnabledObject of type **ProductPromotionEnabled**. What are your takes on this one?

Comment: Just add the `color` attribute regardless if you don't need it  right away. You can say that the color is null or has a value of Zero representing no-color at all.

Comment: @C0dekid  Hi there, I just added my current code implementation.

Comment: @Enzokie Yes, I did exactly that. But is there a better solution in not needing to have a constant placeholder for color, since color null reference are not really logical (if a product doesn't have a color, why do I still need to explicitly tell everyone that it doesn't have a color)?

Comment: `Since color null reference are not really logical` I disagree, the `null` is **a flag** denoting that product has no color. Having a no color attribute at all represents that a product will not have a color at all till eternity. After all this is Java.

Comment: Yes, it is Java. I thought there might be a better way to model the relationship between Product and ProductPromotion in which I don't need to use a null reference for any default Product object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class defines the attribute and behaviour of an entity.
When we put private "ProductPromotion promotion" attribute in the class, it means that all the product should have a promotion and to show that a specific product has no promotion we put a null in there.

It should not be in this way.
A better approach to achieve this is to remove the "private ProductPromotion promotion" attribute from the Product class and the ProductPromotion class should be renamed to PromotedProduct. PromotedProduct should inherit from Product so it would be a specific type of product that has promotion.

In this way we will have two classes. Product and PromotedProduct(specific type of product) and then we can use polymorphism to do operations on the list of products.

Code:

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public Product(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

}

public class PromotedProduct extends Product {

    private Color color;

    public PromotedProduct(String name, BigDecimal price ,Color color) {
        super(name ,price);
        this.color = color;
    }
}

Product product[3];
product[0] = new Product("keyboard",100);
product[1] = new PromotedProduct("stick", 80 ,Color.RED);
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi there, yes I also was thinking about this step. But the problem arises, let's say I have a product: coke zero. In summer time this product will be promoted with a certain color, but after summer it will revert back to its original form with no colors attached. How would you model this particular scenario?

Comment: We have to make a new copy of the object every time it is promoted and reverted back.

I think a better way of doing this is creating new constructors and getter so the following code can be executed.

product[0] = new PromotedProduct(product[0], Color.RED);
product[0] = product[0].getProduct();

Comment: yes, you got a point there. Making product objects immutable is as safe as it gets. Could you elaborate with me how I would achieve this in accordance with a database? E.g. we have a product coke which currently is stored in the db_table_products with a pk=1. Now it gets promoted, so the old entry with pk=1 will be deleted and a new entry with autoincremented pk=10 will be added to db_table? So each time a product changes its promotion -> delete old entry, create new entry?

Comment: In terms of database
Create two tables, product (ID, name, price) and promotedProduct(ID, Color). The primary key of promotedProduct is foreign key referencing product.ID.
In this way a product is added in the product table. When it is promoted, add its ID and color in the promotedProduct table and when it is reverted back just delete its entry from the promotedProduct.

Comment: I fully understand the situation now. Thank you so much for taking your time to help me in this matter. I mark your answer as most helpful in finding a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class `Optional`. That does away with `null` values, and actually it seems you want that relation as such.

```
private Optional<ProductPromotion> promotion = Optional.empty();

promotion.ifPresent(promo -> promo...);
```

The other way would be to map products to promotions.

Comment: Your code will definitely help to circumvent NULL Pointer Exceptions. I am rather looking for a way to model the relationship between Product and ProductPromotion, so that any product can easily switch being in promotion or not in promotion.